# Really slow mysql query for game hiscores

Tags: mysql

The DB is like 4000 rows and is taking ~45 seconds. Index is on game. Multiple and duplicate hiscore entries can exist for each user (not duplicate rows, primary key id exists).

```
SELECT id, username, score, comment, playtime, stage, difficulty, platform
FROM hiscores WHERE game='game_1' AND score
IN (SELECT MAX(score) FROM hiscores WHERE game='game_1' GROUP BY username,difficulty,platform)
GROUP BY username,difficulty,platform ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This is doing 4000*4000 select operations, right? No wonder it's slow. How do I go about fixing this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this bit...

```
SELECT username
     , difficulty
     , platform
     , MAX(score) max_score 
  FROM hiscores 
 WHERE game = 'game_1' 
 GROUP 
    BY username
     , difficulty
     , platform
```

...now, any idea what to do next?

Comment: But...this really is the answer...how could I have missed that? Sure, I've been doing changes to how I work this but from the start it needed that original join.

Comment: And a "thanks" should have been in the previous comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `in`:

```
SELECT id, username, score, comment, playtime, stage, difficulty, platform
FROM hiscores h WHERE game='game_1'
  AND id = 
    (SELECT id FROM hiscores WHERE game='game_1' and (username,difficulty,platform)=(h.username,h.difficulty,h.platform) order by score desc limit 1)
GROUP BY username,difficulty,platform ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think this will work for you. Try this

```
SELECT id, username, score, comment, playtime, stage, difficulty, platform
FROM hiscores h1 JOIN 
(
   SELECT MAX(score) FROM hiscores WHERE game='game_1' GROUP BY username,difficulty,platform
)SUB_TABLE ON h1.score = SUB_TABLE.score
WHERE game='game_1' 
ORDER BY score DESC;
```